# how to combine three list into one list by specious format such as dictionary or JSON ? Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have three lists:

```
imglist=['1.jpg', '12.jpg']
classlist=['class1', 'class5']
sentencelist=['Good for health.', 'Good luck.']
```

how to combine the list into following format?

```
[ ['1.jpg','class1','Good for health.'],
['12.jpg','class5','Good luck.']]
```

or if u know how to combine the lists as dictionary or JSON format ? such as

```
[{'img':'1.jpg','class':'class1','sentence':'Good for health.'},
{'img':'12.jpg','class':'class5','sentence':'Good luck'}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the list as:

```
>>> imglist=['1.jpg', '12.jpg']
>>> classlist=['class1', 'class5']
>>> sentencelist=['Good for health.', 'Good luck.']

# combining list
>>> zip(imglist, classlist, sentencelist)
[('1.jpg', 'class1', 'Good for health.'), ('12.jpg', 'class5', 'Good luck.')]
```

For converting it to `dict` of your format, use `zip` with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> key_list = ["img", "class", "sentence"]
>>> my_zipped_list = zip(imglist, classlist, sentencelist)  # same list as above example

>>> [dict(zip(key_list, zipped_element)) for zipped_element in my_zipped_list]
[{'class': 'class1', 'img': '1.jpg',  'sentence': 'Good for health.'},
 {'class': 'class5', 'img': '12.jpg', 'sentence': 'Good luck.'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in `zip()` or `izip()` method from itertools package.

```
from itertools import izip
for i, j in izip(handle1, handle2):
    ...
```